# How do we implement the AJAX HTTPObject to update a textbox on click of a button in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, javascript

How do we implement the AJAX HTTPObject to update a textbox on click of a button in ASP.Net and javascript. Would the same code apply if the updation would be done on a datagrid ? I read about an implementation of HTTPObject on my own blog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't reimplement this.  Find a nice javascript toolkit like jQuery (or Prototype, MooTools, Dojo, ...) that has an AJAX implementation and use it.  You'll save yourself a lot of grief with cross-browser support if you use an existing implementation that's already been well tested in practical usage.

Example using jQuery:

```
$('#myButton').click( function() {
   $.ajax({
        url: '/example.com/findsomething',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#myTextBox').val( data.value );
        }
   });
});
```

This assumes that the value is retrieved via a GET request and is returned in JSON object with the following format:  `{ value: 'the actual value' }`;